# Com Objects in Powershell (BMC Remedy)

Tags: windows, powershell, remedy

I apologize for the vagueness of this question, but my googling is getting me nowhere fast.  I use a BMC software called AR System User, aka REMEDY. (version 7.6.04)

The installer for this software creates a COM object for use in things like PowerShell.  the following example works 100% on Windows 7 32bit

ex:

```
New-Object -ComObject "ArSystem.User"
```

The EXACT same installer in Windows 10 64bit, installs the application, which works completely fine, however after the install there is no COM object (code above does not work)

I checked the registry for the entry in CLASSES, with no luck, comparing it to windows 7 I can clearly see it.

The software version I am stuck using is no longer supported by BMC, and I have tried installing in compatibility mode with no change.

I do not know enough about COM objects to even begin to troubleshoot this.

Any help would be very appreciated.  I understand the situation is obscure and specific, however I am hoping the basic config for COM objects is universal enough that someone can shed some light.

Thanks anyone who offers a suggestion.

Comment: Hopefully this isn't too obvious, but if the object works in 32-bit but not 64-bit, then the component will only work in a 32-bit PowerShell instance.

Comment: Good point and sorry I didn't mention it above, the object does not work in either version of PowerShell, 32 or 64

Comment: That's not a question we can answer for you here. Sounds like you will need to use a supported version.

Comment: there does not exist a supported version, and migration to a new software is lengthy.  Is there not a way to manually register a com object?

Comment: Yes, but the installer should be doing that for you. If that does not work, you need to talk to the vendor/author of the installer.

Comment: I agree it should, the vendor will no longer support.  So again I am asking if there is a way to force it manually.  You said "Yes", if that's true can you point me in the direction to get this done.  I agree we need new software, I agree the vendor could help if it was supported, but until we can complete a migration of our data and test it thoroughly, we need a workaround.

Comment: This would be a more appropriate question for superuser or server fault than stackoverflow.